# Can i use html code within "@()" in razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I want to use html code in ternary operator within @() brackets.

Example:

```
<h1 class="display-4">Welcome @(SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) ? @user.FirstName : "Maybe you wanna log in?")</h1>
```

I want to make "Maybe you wanna log in?" into another line, with br/, /n or anything else.
How can i do it without going to another line of code?

Comment: Instead of using `@(...)` I use `@{....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Html.Raw` to prevent rendered HTML from getting encoded:

```
<h1 class="display-4">Welcome @(SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) ? user.FirstName : Html.Raw("Maybe you wanna<br> log in?"))</h1>
```